# modify qscintilla python lexar

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qscintilla

Similar to this question: [Creating and colorizing new constructs on a existing Scintilla lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021294/creating-and-colorizing-new-constructs-on-a-existing-scintilla-lexer) but instead of adding, I would like to modify text colors of the lexer in pyqt4.  The closes I found is [QScintilla: how to create a new lexer or modify an existing one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097773/qscintilla-how-to-create-a-new-lexer-or-modify-an-existing-one) in which the user just gave up.

Basically I would like to switch to a darker text editor theme, such as MAYA (Not the same keyword/syntax highlighting, just the overall color theme):
 [image]

I have been able to modify some open code online to set my background and default text:

```
lexer = getattr(Qsci, 'QsciLexer' + 'Python')()
lexer.setDefaultFont(font)
lexer.setDefaultPaper(QColor("#3c3c3c"))
lexer.setDefaultColor(QColor("#f9f9f9"))
self.setLexer(lexer)
self.SendScintilla(QsciScintilla.SCI_STYLESETFONT, 1, 'Helvetica')
```

I cant find access to setting colors for the python lexer like comments, imports, exceptions, etc.

Comment: There is a new website with a beginners tutorial on QScintilla: http://qscintilla.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the foreground colour for e.g. comments:

```
    lexer.setColor(QColor('lightblue'), QsciLexerPython.Comment)
```

To set the background colour:

```
    lexer.setPaper(QColor('darkblue'), QsciLexerPython.Comment)
```

To set the font:

```
    lexer.setFont(QFont('DejaVu Sans'), QsciLexerPython.Comment)
```

For other possibilities, consult the [QScintilla docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/index.html).